# FULLTEXT search ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, mariadb-10.3

I have tabl_1 records follow:

```
Balvenie 12
Balvenie 13
Balvenie 14
Balvenie 15
Balvenie 16
**Balvenie 17**
Balvenie 18
Balvenie 19
Balvenie 20
Balvenie 21
Balvenie 22
```

How do I state the search query? with type FULLTEXT:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST("Balvenie 17")
FROM view_product 
ORDER BY ??
```

I look forward to showing results:

```
**Balvenie 17**
Balvenie 12
Balvenie 13
Balvenie 14
Balvenie 15
Balvenie 16
Balvenie 18
Balvenie 19
Balvenie 20
Balvenie 21
Balvenie 22
```

I am trying to sort search query statement FULLTEXT search to sort - ORDER BY